# Serialization issue using JsonConvert.SerializeObject (properties missing on server)

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am getting pretty weird behaviour using JsonConvert.SerializeObject.

I have a method looking like the following:

```
public class ServiceController : ApiController
{
    public object GetJSONConnectedResponse(object input)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input, Formatting.Indented,
        new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize
        });
    }


    public object GetMediaGallery(int? id)
    {
        try
        {
            return GetJSONConnectedResponse(GalleryBLL.GetMediaGallery(id));
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            LogBLL.LogException(exc, HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using MVC Web API as a service application from which I query ajax-type of data using javascript on the client side.

The method GetMediaGallery returns a holder class of the following structure:

```
public class MediaGalleryHolder
{
    public List<DB_Image> Images { get; set; }
    public List<string> SpinFrames { get; set; }
    public string FlyoverVideo { get; set; }
}
```

DB_Images is a complex entity which I populate in a business logic method by calling a stored procedure. On this complex entity, I have added 2 extra properties.

```
public partial class DB_Image
{
    public string FullPath { get; set; }
    public string ThumbPath { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason, on my local machine, the result serializes correctly (adding both the 2 extra properties), but on the server those extra properties are not added to the result (I know they are populated, but never serialized).

Is this some sort of JSON.NET or MVC Web API versioning issue, how can I go about to troubleshoot or resolve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Best,

tribe84

Comment: Did you check if you are getting data out of the stored procedure on the server?

Comment: Yes, its literally the same code, connecting to the same database (from different servers).

Comment: Are you certain you have the same version of MVC installed? Are you sure it is the one being used by your application?

Comment: I am not sure... is there a easy way to see which version of MVC is installed on a machine?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with annotations on each class?
you can try adding [Serializable]

```
  [Serializable] 
  public partial class DB_Image
  {
        public string FullPath { get; set; }
        public string ThumbPath { get; set; }
  }

  [Serializable]
  public class MediaGalleryHolder
  {
       public List<DB_Image> Images { get; set; }
       public List<string> SpinFrames { get; set; }
       public string FlyoverVideo { get; set; }
  }
```

Hope it helps!